# python unicode contains '\u000A' convert make Chinese error

Tags: python, unicode, encode

I want to convert this string to correct string, how I can convert `\\uOOOA` to '\n' without make Chinese wrong code

```
# string
s = u'蛋疼\\u000A egg烦'
```

I tried this

```
s.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
```

This corrects the `\\u000A`, but turns the Chinese text into unreadable gibberish:

```
èç¼
 eggç¦
```

I got the string from Javascript code in an HTML page.

Comment: Is this JSON perhaps?

Comment: In other words, *where did this data come from*, you can probably avoid this altogether by using a better way to extract it.

Comment: No, this is unicode string contains '\\u000A' and Chinese , i want to convert '\\u000A' to '\n' and make Chinese unchanged.

Comment: This string is from html

Comment: So this is *Javascript* text perhaps? HTML doesn't support such escapes.

Comment: Yes,  but how can i replace '\\u000A' with '\n'

Comment: `u'蛋疼\\uOOOA egg烦'` should be `u'蛋疼\u000A egg烦'`. Note zeroes instead of _Latin Capital Letter O_s **and** a single backslash instead of double one.

Comment: You already asked me that 3 times. Now that I have enough context, we can start answering.

Comment: Ok,  i use s.replace('\\u000A', '\u000A') but it doesn't work well

Comment: @JosefZ: the `O`s are just a typo in their attempt to create a MCVE. The backslash is a *literal in their actual data*, so doubling it in the MCVE is *not* a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unicode-escape` decodes un-escaped bytes as *Latin-1* first. It is also the wrong method to use for Javascript data; Python and Javascript syntax differ subtly and there are edge-cases where you'll get the wrong result.

Instead, treat the data as *JSON*. A Javascript string can always be treated as a JSON string type, provided you retain the quoting:

```
s = u'"蛋疼\\u000A egg烦"'
```

Note that that string starts and ends with `"` and `"` now. The original Javascript string definition in the HTML page would do too.

When you extract the data from the HTML page, **keep** the double quotes, then pass this to `json.loads()`:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = u'"蛋疼\\u000A egg烦"'
>>> json.loads(s)
u'\u86cb\u75bc\n egg\u70e6'
>>> print json.loads(s)
蛋疼
 egg烦
```

Answer (score -2):

Learn by example:

```
==> python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> # original
...
>>> s= u'蛋疼\\u000A egg烦'
>>> s
'蛋疼\\u000A egg烦'
>>> print(s)
蛋疼\u000A egg烦
>>>
>>>
>>> # answer
...
>>> s= u'蛋疼\u000A egg烦'
>>> s
'蛋疼\n egg烦'
>>> print(s)
蛋疼
 egg烦
>>>
```

Comment: The **actual data they scraped** contains a literal backslash,  the letter `u` and the 4 hex digits. This is not a question about how to construct a Python string literal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I **see** an **assignment** `s = u'蛋疼\\u000A egg烦'` in the original question, sorry.

Comment: Yes, but that's just to produce an MCVE, to reproduce the actual data that came from elsewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think that an answer **should** or **must** give  a _generally valid_ MCVE to any Q even its formulation seems to cover very particular assignment case?